# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE issue

Tags: php, mysql

Hi could some one look at this and tell me where I am going wrong.
I have an SQL statement that when I echo using php I get this to screen

```
INSERT INTO 'moviedb'.'genre' SET 'GenreID' = '18' , 'GenreName' = 'Drama' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'GenreName' = 'Drama' WHERE 'GenreID' = '18'
INSERT INTO 'moviedb'.'genre' SET 'GenreID' = '16' , 'GenreName' = 'Animation' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'GenreName' = 'Animation' WHERE 'GenreID' = '16'
```

And here is the statement

```
$sql="INSERT INTO 'moviedb'.'genre' SET 'GenreID' = '{$genresID[$i]}' , 'GenreName' = '{$genreName[$i]}' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'GenreName' = '{$genreName[$i]}' WHERE 'GenreID' = '{$genresID[$i]}'";
```

This is the error I recieve:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''moviedb'.'genre' SET 'GenreID' = '18' , 'GenreName' = 'Drama' ON DUPLICATE KEY ' at line 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot combine a `WHERE` with a `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Remove the `WHERE` clause, MySql will only update the row that causes the duplicate key.

For a multi row `INSERT`, use the `VALUES()` to tell MySql to update the value that would of inserted, example:

```
INSERT INTO moviedb.genre (GenreID,GenreName)
VALUES ('18', 'Drama'),
    ('16', 'Animation')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  GenreName = VALUES(GenreName);
```

Comment: Thanks every1.....spent so long trying to figure that one out. Every1 deserves a tick.

Answer (score 3):

You are quoting the mysql fields...

You should be using backticks (`) instead of single quotes... Single quotes are for values, backticks are for fields.

```
INSERT INTO `moviedb`.`genre` SET `GenreID` = '18' , `GenreName` = 'Drama' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `GenreName` = VALUES(`GenreName`);
INSERT INTO `moviedb`.`genre` SET `GenreID` = '16' , `GenreName` = 'Animation' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `GenreName` = VALUES(`GenreName`);
```

Comment: Is it the exact same error? As The Scrum Meister said, remove the where in the ON DUPLICATE KEY... it will automatically be doing the row there the duplicate was.

Comment: yea sorted, thanks a lot, late night coding is having an effect on my thought process. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `moviedb`.`genre` SET `GenreID` = '18' , `GenreName` = 'Drama' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `GenreName` = 'Drama' WHERE `GenreID` = '18'
INSERT INTO `moviedb`.`genre` SET `GenreID` = '16' , `GenreName` = 'Animation' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `GenreName` = 'Animation' WHERE `GenreID` = '16'
```

and you're all set.